# Expanding a hidden div by referring with an anchor from external page

Tags: javascript, anchor, hidden

I have a script which hides (display:none) certain divs in the list on page load. Div contents represents description of a book, and the whole list is some sort of bibliography.  Every div has an id, for example, "div1", "div2" etc.

```
<ul>  
<li><div class="hidden" id="div1"></li>  
<li><div class="hidden" id="div1"></li>   
...  
</ul>
```

And there's another page with a menu, which consists of anchored links to every such a div:

```
<ul>  
<li><a href="bibl.html#div1"></li>  
<li><a href="bibl.html#div2"></li>  
...  
</ul>
```

I want the hidden div to autoexpand when the link on another page is clicked. I tried some window.location.href stuff, but to no avail - my JS is weak yet. As I understand the logic it should take the current url and check it for "#", then search for an element with the part to the right in the id attribute. Thanks a lot kind people.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this on the target page:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash; // would be "#div1" or something
    if(hash != "") {
        var id = hash.substr(1); // get rid of #
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Essentially, you check on the page load whether the window's href has a hash attached to it. If it does, you find the `<div>` and change the style display to block.

Comment: There. Happy now? You got one :)

Comment: No, I'm not happy. I'm on the warpath for PHP questions, I'm SOOO close to the Gold I can smell it! :)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you might want to add `location.href = '#' + id;` as the last line after changing style to actually scroll to this element

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I figured out you can add this

```
location.href = '#' + id;
```

and also have the page scrolled to the position of the referred div.

Comment: Shouldn't it do that automatically?

Comment: @PaoloBergantino it does only if the element was shown when page was loaded. However if we use JS code from the accepted answer, then you don't get any scrolling (which makes sense, because sequence of events is somehow like `load page code` -> `auto-scroll to the hash` -> `execute JS`). But if you add this line as the last line to the function from accepted answer, you get it working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.location.hash` to see the hash value.
From there you can `getElementById(hashValue)` and show it.