# show hidden div tag from another page

Tags: javascript, function, html, hashtag

I'm trying to link to an all-inclusive FAQ page from various pages. The answers are contained in  tags, nested within a line item of an unordered list housed by categories.

The FAQ page has the following categories:

1. Practical Nurse Exam
2. Online Renewal
3. Practice Hours

etc.

Under Practical Nurse Exam, there are sub categories, subjects, with questions below in  tags that expand onClick. (e.g. Examination Day, Exam Results, etc.)

Let's say I'm on a different page called Registration and there's a link to the FAQs for Exam Results.

I'm able to link to the page and included the hashtag on the anchor or Exam Results, but it does not expand the subcategory.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103406/expanding-a-hidden-div-by-referring-with-an-anchor-from-external-page) thread but it didn't work for me. Please help! The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(Info,pic) {
      var CState = document.getElementById(Info);
      CState.style.display = (CState.style.display != 'block') ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash; // would be "#div1" or something
        if(hash != "") {
            var id = hash.substr(1); // get rid of #
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    </script>

<style type="text/css">
 .FAQ { cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; }
 .FAA { display:none;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-indent:-20px; }
 #FAQlist li { list-style-type: none; }
 #FAQlist ul { margin-left:0px; }
 headingOne{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#66BBFF; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;}

</style>
```

Here's the body (part of it anyway)

```
<headingOne class="FAQ" onClick="toggle('CPNRE', this)">PRACTICAL NURSE EXAM</headingOne>
<div class="FAA" id="CPNRE">
<h3><a name="applying">Applying to write the CPNRE</a></h3>
<ul id="FAQlist" style="width:450px;">
    <li class="FAQ">
        <p onclick="toggle('faq1',this)">
            <strong>Q: How much does it cost to write the exam?</strong></p>
        <div class="FAA" id="faq1">
      <b>A.</b> In 2013, the cost for the first exam writing is $600.00 which includes the interim license fee. See <a href="https://www.clpnbc.org/What-is-an-LPN/Becoming-an-LPN/Canadian-Practical-Nurse-Registration-Examination/Fees-and-Deadlines.aspx"> fee schedule</a>.</div>
        <hr />
    </li>
```

and here's the body of the other page that contains the link and the same script syntax as the all-inclusive FAQ page. This is just a test, that's not exactly what it will say:

```
<a onclick="toggle('CPNRE', this)" href="file:///S|/Designs/Web stuff/FAQ all inclusive.html#applying"> click here</a>
```

Comment: If the link is on a different page, linking *to* your FAQ page, you don't need an onlick because the toggle occurs when the FAQ page loads.

Comment: @Diodeus Hello! Thanks for commenting. So you mean I don't need the onclick on the other page but just need the href, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the div you are trying to expand is within other divs that are collapsed, you will have to expand the container divs before expanding the children divs in order for them to show. 
So you need to at least call something like the toggle function in the head code, for example

```
window.onload = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash; // would be "#div1" or something
        if(hash != "") {
            toggle('CPNRE', this);/*this is an example the CPNRE value needs to be figured out*/
            var id = hash.substr(1); // get rid of #
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

This is roughly the idea not a complete solution since you do need to figure out the container div to call toggle or some other function for it to expand.

**EDIT**

One way of achieving what you are trying to do, in pure js, would be to do the following,

```
if(hash != "") {
    var id = hash.substr(1); // get rid of #
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';   
    document.getElementById(id).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById(id).parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById(id).parentNode.style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
}
```

But this is related to the specific layout you have provided in your question.

A better, more generic, solution would be to iterate the parents until a specific parent is found based on the class value, for example

**HTML**

```
/*add class value like faq-section to each div section */
<div class="FAA faq-section" id="faq1">
```

**js**

```
....
if(hash != "") {
  var id= hash.substr(1);
  var pNode = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
  var endLoop=false;
  while(!endLoop){
    if(pNode.className&&pNode.className.indexOf('faq-section')!=-1){
      endLoop=true;
    };
    pNode.style.display='block';
    pNode=pNode.parentNode;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying! I was really going crazy (I don't have much js knowledge. I should have paid attention in class). the CPNRE info above is one heading. Should I leave it blank so that it can populate different headings, as well? (I'll figure out the lower levels later. I'd be happy enough if it could at least toggle each section. Right now, it can only do the first one, which is 'CPNRE'.

Thank you very much again for replying :)

Comment: I took this out because I don't think I need it:

'code' var id= hash.substr(1); 'code'

I'm thinking that the 'code' toggle ('CPNRE', this) 'code' should change. I was able to expand one heading at a time by changing the 'Info' but I'm not sure how I can make it so that it will accept a variable. I tried leaving it blank, tried '', and CState but nothing. Sorry, I'm such a noob. :(

Comment: @neueweblernen updated the answer with a possible solution, hope it helps.

Comment: HAHA!!!! It WORKS!!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you! XD I didn't even need to put anchors. You're awesome! :)