# Anchor link to content inside hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm trying to link to content from an external page, using

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
```

and

```
<a href="/somepage/#anchor"></a>
```

The content where the anchor is located is hidden inside a drawer, using jQuery:

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bd1mbu5j/1/

I've tried wrapping my head around the method [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103406/expanding-a-hidden-div-by-referring-with-an-anchor-from-external-page), but I know there's something I'm missing.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash; // would be "#div1" or something
    if(hash != "") {
        var id = hash.substr(1); // get rid of #
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Also should be noted, I'm not just trying to open the drawer, but link to specific content within certain drawers.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bd1mbu5j/2/

```
  $(".toggle_container").hide();
  $("h3.trigger").click(function(){
    var _this = this;
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("normal", function () {
        var anchor = $(_this).data('anchor');
        console.log(anchor);

        if (anchor && $('#'+anchor).length) {
            console.log($('#'+anchor).offset().top);
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+anchor).offset().top+'px'});
        }
    });

    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
  });
```

I added the target element id as a data attribute and picked that up once the slide toggle was finished. Then I animated down to that element if it exists.

Comment: Hey David, I'm actually looking to have that "Anchor Link" open the toggle, and send you to the anchor. I don't want to scroll once the toggle's already open.

Comment: I'm not if I understand what you are requesting - do you mean the current functionality should be on the anchor link insetad?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Starting from an external page, I want to have a link (ie. /somepage/#anchor") take me to /somepage/ where the toggles are located, open the toggle containing the #anchor, and scroll to the anchor.

Comment: Still struggling with this. Have you had any luck? Thanks!